# registerUserNotificationSettings only asks me once if "APPNAME would like to use push notifications". I need it to ask me again for testing. How?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I'm testing Push Notifications right now.

`registerUserNotificationSettings` is supposed to ask the user once and only once if "APPNAME would like to send Push Notifications". However, I'm testing my app right now and I need it to ask me again. I've deleted the application from my device, and re-run the application on my device from XCode but I cannot get it to ask me again.

What do I need to delete from my device to get this question to show up again?

Comment: I think you need to reset the device. Settings > General > Reset.

Comment: @matt yikes that's the only option?? That's crazy.

Comment: Well, you _could_ reinstall the system. :) Seriously, you need to make the device forget that it has _ever_ seen this app. This is how you do that. What do you care? It's only a test device - isn't it???

Comment: @matt nope it's my main device. I want to move the register call elsewhere in the code, after the use has made his/her first comment. This way the conversion rate of people accepting push notifications will be higher since they want them on when someone comments on their post. Would like to test it tho.

Comment: Well, it isn't so terrible. I've done this a gazillion times, for the same sort of reason (e.g. when testing the authorization dialog for the address book).

Comment: @matt I found the answer and posted it

Comment: Ooooh, what a sneaky solution! And it comes from Apple!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42

**Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS**

The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:

1) Delete your app from the device.

2) Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.

3) Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.

4) Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a rather obvious solution, but if your test device is your main (personal) device, you can test this using the **simulator**, which is of course very easy to reset.

This would be much faster than turning you device off/on, change date, turn off/on again.